How do I add the 'One Calendar' app to Task Scheduler?
Whenever I create a basic task or create task with the 'One Calendar' app from the Microsoft Store on Windows 10, I get a "Catastrophic Failure" error message. This happens when I go to add the shortcut of the 'One Calendar' app under the 'Program/Script' section by browsing for the shortcut itself which is located on my desktop.
Can anybody help me?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Try running Task Scheduler as an administrator and ensure the shortcut path is correct. If that doesn't work, recreate the shortcut or reinstall the 'One Calendar' app from the Microsoft Store.

The environment of tasks that are run by Task Scheduler is different than
tasks that are run from inside the logon session.
The One Calendar app may not run correctly in that environment.
If you wish to have it run automatically when you logon,
I suggest to place the shortcut to One Calendar in the Startup group at
C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup,
so it will be started when you logon, and from inside your
logon environment.
